# How to source zshrc from bash script

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a script written in bash that sets up my zsh config and changes current user's shell to zsh if needed/possible. After default shell is changed, I want zsh to load my new profile, but when I do a regular `source`, it opens in shell run by script (bash).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't find any step in your question, where you actually *start* the Z shell... so probably you want to include a `exec /bin/zsh` in your (bash-) script and then `zsh` will source automatically your zsh config in `~/.zshrc`.

Excerpt from bash's man page:

> `exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]`
>
> If  `command`  is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new process is created (...)

Comment: I rechecked my code and found that I did my exec wrong using ``. Thanks!